# Can we add muliple document.ready functions in a jsp page with unique API calls inside them?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp, getjson, document-ready

When I added multiple document.ready functions in a jsp page with unique API calls inside each of the document.ready function I see a error in the google chrome console like follows. And the relevent data is not loaded to the web page.

:8080/myurl/restcall
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 ()

Comment: Yes, you can have multiple _document.ready_ handler, the error has nothing to do with that

Comment: How can I fix that error?

Comment: API is returning 500, So error is on the server side debug that

Comment: have you tried **not** having multiple document.ready functions - if you try that, you'll see you **still** get that server side error - as stated above, the error is on server side

Comment: Yes I tried using a single document.ready but the same error was occured.

Comment: Has the problem occurred because of including several API calls inside the same document.ready functions and having many document.ready functions that contains API calls in my code?

Comment: You accepted an answer and then asked follow up questions? You should be asking this is a separate question. When you do you should post your code as indicated by the guidelines provided in the [help]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can have multiple callback function on document.ready

like this

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    console.log( "ready!" );
});
$( document ).ready(function() {
    console.log( "log!" );
});
$( document ).ready(function() {
    console.log( "status!" );
});
```

this have nothing to do with your api response

but you can not have multiple callback function on `window.onload` 
like this

```
window.onload = function() {
  console.log("hello window")
};

window.onload = function() {
  console.log("hello window again")
}
```

because it will overweight the previous one